# How to install Docker on Fedora 35?

Tags: docker, fedora

I tried to install Docker on Fedora 35 with the following commands:

```
sudo dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core
sudo dnf config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/docker-ce.repo
sudo dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

But, I got the 404 error for the repository:

errors during downloading metadata for repository ‘docker-ce-stable’:

Status code: 404 for https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/35/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 13.227.108.44)
Error: Falha ao baixar os metadados do repo. ‘docker-ce-stable’: Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: now in the official repo: https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-35/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on the official Fedora Forum managed to resolve it. So I'll put his answer here (https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/error-on-install-docker-in-fedora-35/17165):

That’s because docker have not yet made a repository for Fedora 35. So for the time being, you’ll have to use their F34 packages. You’ll need to tweak your /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo file to replace $releasever (which on Fedora 35 is 35) with 34.

So, it’ll look like this:

```
[docker-ce-stable]
name=Docker CE Stable - $basearch
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/34/$basearch/stable
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/gpg
...
```

I check from time to time to see if docker have made a repo from F35 yet. When that happens, we’ll need to undo this change.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried these ?

```
sudo dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core

sudo dnf config-manager \
   --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/docker-ce.repo

sudo dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Comment: These were exactly the commands I used.

Comment: in the officiel website this was the instructions to install docker on fedora 33 or 34 . maybe there is another way for fedora 35

Comment: Yes, I read the official documentation to try to install, but it seems to me that they haven't created the folder with the files for Fedora 35 in the Docker repository yet.

Comment: maybe this is a crazy idea . but try to install the docker for fedora 34  on your machine (  this is the link for the stable version https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/34/x86_64/stable/Packages/ ) .just download the packages , install them with rpm and try to manage the missing dependencies. and how knows maube it will work